# How to publish part of an ASP.NET web project from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have an ASP.NET web application and I would like to 'Publish' a new page - but not the whole website (as shown below); how could this be done?

[image]

I am using FTP publishing with pre-compiling; Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms366723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (deploying all source code without compiling and publishing) you can just replace one page, by ftp for example.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be doing this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible to compile and publish just one page however, why dont you compile your website and just upload the page you want to publish? (upload the page by using an FTP client like Filezilla so that you can select which page to upload)

Perhaps you can explain what your motive or goal is to just publish one page and maybe there is another solution to your problem...

Comment: no, you can't upload just one page if you compile it, because you need to replace dlls in bin folder ( they are changing if you only change one page, I mean code behind). So just publish all project.

Comment: Right, thanks. My website is quite large and has big resources in it - uploading every time takes a while.

Comment: @Alex Yes, actually I think you're right; maybe I can't do this :P. Oh well.